# GWT 2.7: What is the difference between -XjsInteropMode JS and -XjsInteropMode CLOSURE?

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, gwt-2.7

I tried out GWT 2.7 and was woundering what is the difference between -XjsInteropMode JS and -XjsInteropMode CLOSURE compiler flag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-XjsInteropMode JS will output standard deobfuscated javascript accessors (method names match up directly, bean getter/setters map to simple property access).  I *assumed* that using CLOSURE option will add Closure type annotations to the output to ensure two-way type safety between Gwt and Closure... But Goktug has replied on G+, saying:

```
-XjsInteropMode CLOSURE was used to generate export code in a way
that was assuming closure goog.provide(...) statements exists in
the beginning of js (potentially produced and prepended by a linker).
It was not useful for general public.

I'm using past tense because the option is now removed from the trunk.
```

Anways, if you are interested in Closure with Gwt, the video is not up yet, but Ray Cromwell's talk about Google Inbox mentions how they support highly optimized, fast compilation of Gwt -> Closure Friendly JS -> Minified obfuscated JS.

When the video is up, check it out here:
http://gwtcreate.com/videos/index.html
Until then, here are the slides:
https://drive.google.com/a/wetheinter.net/file/d/0B3ktS-w9vr8IS2ZwQkw3WVRVeXc/view

Finally, Ray's talk specifically about Js Interop:
https://docs.google.com/a/wetheinter.net/file/d/0ByS1wxINeBWjeGYxbkJpamxFZ28/edit

Note that there is also a video for that talk pending.  It's very good. You should watch them both when they are uploaded.